# Whats the difference between "dropdown/caret" icon and "unfold more" icon?

Tags: forms, icons, tables, dropdown

I usually see this on tables or forms where some are using dropdown and some are using "unfold more" icon. Is there any difference or each icon has its own meaning?

[image]

OR

[image]

Other Reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Icons alone don't mean much. It's the context that provides details as to what it does or what it is.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, they all are sorting icons that represent different state of the sorting. These images were taken from font-awesome.

(http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)

[image: asc]

[image: desc]

[image: sorting icons]

In the case of a **drop-down**, it doesn't make any difference which icon you are going to use, as long as it delivers the message that it is a drop-down.

Both of what you have shown work since they are quite commonly used. Try to keep it **consistent** with the whole system.

Comment: Added a new image that doesn't sort. (I just googled the image)

Comment: not necessarily true for all cases; in the question the "fa-sort" type of icon is used on a drop-down that doesn't imply any type of sorting, it's just an option selection

Comment: @Luciano I added my answer for the drop-down case

Comment: @Luciano exactly like on this link i found: http://thedesigninspiration.com/blog/2013/08/26/40-free-dropdown-and-select-box-psd-designs/

Answer (score 1):

Both the icons which you have attached are totally different.

[image]

- This one can be used as indicator of dropdown in combo-box or menu items.

---

[image]

- This icon is used to increase or decrease values in a input field like a slider.

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get the second icon right, but it looks to me like it's two icons; expand and collapse view. In that case, the one on the left is the same as the bottom one on the right.

[image]

If that's not the case, the two icons are very different. The one on the left is to indicate a dropdown menu and the one on the right can increase or decrease a value. For example in a spinner or slider.

Comment: I added some images which unfold more icon was used for sorting which doesn't define increases or decreases value.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the caret in a user interface simply means "more". It can be used as a toggle to expand/collapse a section, as a dropdown icon, or in a content slider to indicate more content to the right (or left). The direction of the "more" is usually indicated by the direction the caret is pointing.

See this answer: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/21531/9932

And this answer: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/96650/9932

Comment: Does sorting defines "more"?

Comment: In the case of sorting a caret isn't used unless a column has been sorted. The caret is usually an indicator of two things: 1. that the column is sorted vs not sorted, and 2. the direction of the sort (asc vs desc). Therefore the caret is not indicating "more" in a sort, and usually isn't displayed until after the user decides to sort a column.

See this answer: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/80660/9932

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, those icons are different.

I have never seen a sort icon that uses chevrons, I have only seen it using arrow triangles.

The expand chevron indicates hidden content that typically appears below something, for example a heading in a box which is expandable and collapsable, for example an accordion.

The unfold icon to me indicates that you can unfold content inbetween content. For example when you search for a public transport trip and you'll first see only start and end destination. I would use this icon to unfold the stops inbetween start and end destination.

[image: unfold more icon used to unfold stops between start and end destination of a trip]

Answer (score 0):

**It completely depends on the context of usage.**

1. Drop down or sorting
2. Next / Previous or  Up / Down or Increase / Decrease